# How to Add Meta tags in Shopify Theme Site?

Tags: seo, shopify, meta-tags

I have a site designed in Shopify platform But unable to insert Meta Title, Description, Keywords.

Also I want to implement Meta Tags in its pages & products. But don't know how to add them?

Answer (score 1):

If you based your theme on one of the standard ones you should see some tags in the main layout like:

```
{% if page_description %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}">
{% endif %}
```

If not you can add it and get a meta tag.

If you want to add more info you'll need decide where the info is going to come from and code your theme accordingly. Again if you based your theme on a standard theme your main layout may have a snippet reference for open-graph-tags.  If you edit open-graph-tags.liquid you will see one way to manage conditional meta tags.

In a nutshell you'd put something like the following in your theme header where XXX is the field that has your keywords. (maybe use a metafield for this?) :

```
{% if template contains 'product' %}
      <meta name="keywords" content="{{ product.XXX | strip_html | escape }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Genius, you saved my life, but how do I add more metafields to this when i have 2 authors for a book selling website.